# Is it good to ignore (@) errors that happen due to external factors?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a LDAP server request in my code. I open an connection with `ldap_connect` and check that returned descriptor is valid, but then I make a search request with `ldap_search` using the open descriptor. But sometimes due to the network failure or something else, `ldap_search` fails with warning `Search: Can't contact LDAP server`.

On my production server I treat all warnings as fatal errors, so the whole page render fails.

Should I just prepend `ldap_search` with `@` and just check the value returned (I do check it now as well) or there's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn warnings into Exceptions by [setting your own error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Just catch all warnings and throw an Exception inside the callback. That way you won't have to deal with the unwanted output, but have a chance to recover (direct the user to a temporary-error-page), which you can't do with fatal errors.

Sometimes an external resource throws a warning, and also lets you check if an error occurred (mysqli for example.) In this case you can ignore the warning with `@`, but make sure you check if an error occurred.

**I would not just suppress a warning, without making sure that it is dealt with in some other way.** Users want to know why something went wrong, especially if the situation is only temporary.

As a side note: I think warnings in php are a rediculous concept. Code either fails or it doesn't. If it fails, I want to be able to deal with it, without jumping through hoops. Just throw me an exception, please!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd agree with you, just shove a `@` there and manually check for error conditions - I do this for `mysql_connect` and `Memcache->connect`, and any `fsockopen` calls I make, as this can also allow for things like "try again a few times before dying".

However, I'm sure most nuts would tell you you should never use `@` and you should use custom error handlers instead. So... up to you!